# SUM for distinct names in SAS EG

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I am trying to find the sum of the prices of the products that correspond to each customer, but cannot find the distinct sum for each customer name:

```
SUM of total price | Product ID | Order ID| Customer name

$71.97        240400300006  1235822165  Alberta Beasley
$67.50        230100600041  1238001242  Alberta Beasley
$26.90        240700200010  1236974404  Alberta Beasley
$249.60   230100100045  1230873918  Alberta Cacitti
$204.40   220200100044  1242419364  Alberta Cacitti
$143.70   220200100056  1239120771  Alberta Cacitti
```

I want my output to be:

```
Alberta Beasley  $166.37
Alberta Cacitti  $597.7
```

Any ideas please?

Comment: Are you asking for code or asking how to do it in the EG point/click?

Comment: Use the Summary Task

Answer (score 0):

Here are three of many possible approaches. In each o the methods you are telling SAS that you want to group the data by the column `name` and sum up the values in the column `price` for each group.

using `proc summary` (or `proc means`):

```
proc summary data = have nway;
    class name;
    output out = want
        sum(price) = total;
run;
```

Using `proc sql`:

```
proc sql;
    create table want as
    select name, sum(price) as total
    from have
    group by name;
quit;
```

Using EG's query builder (this is from memory so the names may be a bit off):

- Open the dataset
- Select Query Builder
- Drag `name` and `price` across into the Select Data pane
- Set the Summary column to "SUM" for the `price` row
- Select Edit Groups and select name
- Press Run